# GTKSharp, Increasing the text size of a Menu Bar using Mondevelop,Stetic GUI Designer

Tags: c#, monodevelop, gtk#

I am wondering if anyone can help me. I am trying to figure out, how to increase the text inside a menu bar using mono develop. I can increase the size of text in labels and such using

```
public static FontDescription Font(string Family, int Size, Pango.Style Sty = Pango.Style.Normal)
{
    var F = new FontDescription
    {
        Family = Family,
        Size = Convert.ToInt32(Size * Pango.Scale.PangoScale),
        Style = Sty
    };
    return F;
}
```

And then:

```
 var test = Font("Verdana", 24);
 label1.ModifyFont(test);
```

But when I do this it wont work

```
MainMenuBar.ModifyFont(test);
```

[image: Cant Increase the size of the text with the menu bar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Widget](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3AGtk.Widget).[ModifyFont](http://docs.go-mono.com/monodoc.ashx?link=M%3AGtk.Widget.ModifyFont(Pango.FontDescription))([Pango.FontDescription fd](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=T%3APango.FontDescription)). This method is available in all classes, since it derives from **Widget**.

However, you cannot change the font of a **MenuBar** and expect all child **MenuItem**'s fonts. This does not even work for a **MenuItem**: you have to change the **Label** inside it, normally accessible by **MenuItem.Child**.

I have prepared a pair of functions that do the trick:

```
public static void ChangeContainerFont(Gtk.Container container, string fontDesc)
{
    ChangeWidgetFont( container, fontDesc );

    foreach(Gtk.Widget subw in container.Children) {
        ChangeWidgetFont( subw, fontDesc );

        if ( subw is Gtk.MenuItem menuItem ) {
            var subMenu = menuItem.Submenu;
            ChangeContainerFont( menuItem, fontDesc );

            if ( subMenu is Gtk.Container subContainer ) {
                ChangeContainerFont( subContainer, fontDesc );
            } else {
                if ( subMenu != null ) {
                    ChangeWidgetFont( subMenu, fontDesc );
                }
            }
        } else
        if ( subw is Gtk.Container subContainer ) {
            ChangeContainerFont( subContainer, fontDesc );
        }
    }
}

public static void ChangeWidgetFont(Gtk.Widget w, string fontDesc)
{
    w.ModifyFont( Pango.FontDescription.FromString( fontDesc ) );
}
```

You can call *ChangeContainerFont(c, s)* programmatically after the UI has been built (give your menu bar an intuitive name such as *menuBar*):

```
ChangeContainerFont( menuBar, "Times 22" );
```

This will run through all **MenuItem**'s inside, stopping once it reaches a wiget which is not a container. For example, **MenuBar** or **MenuItem** are containers (the former contains **MenuItem**'s, the latter contains at least a **Label**), while a **Label** is not.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It seems when I do this it has no effect, on both options.

Comment: I've been able to solve it; check out my (this one, edited) question.

Comment: Thanks for that, but it seems not increase the size of the children, like New Project

Comment: That 's because a MenuItem has children (typically just one child: a Label), and then another container in Submenu which typically points to a Gtk.Menu. Solved now.